# How to give a friendly error message inside a modal with Bootstrap form?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-modal

How do I give an error message inside modal after clicking update?

In my example here I gave a `required` attribute on the input field.
I want to change the error message based on [Form Validation Best Practices](https://medium.com/@andrew.burton/form-validation-best-practices-8e3bec7d0549).

(This code is part of CRUD PHP file for updating data in a table I had)

```html
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Data</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="form-update" action="proses_edit.php" name="modal_popup" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                
                <div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
                    <label for="Name">Name</label>
                    <input type="hidden" name="modal_id" id="edit-id"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo $r['modal_id']; ?>"/>
                    <input type="text" name="modal_name" id="edit-name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $r['modal_name']; ?>" required />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
                    <label for="Description">Age</label>
                    <input type="text" id="edit-description" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $r['description']; ?>" required />
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
                        Update
                    </button>

                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                        Cancel
                    </button>
                </div>

                </form>

            </div>
           
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here’s how form validation works with Bootstrap, taken from the documentation:

> - HTML form validation is applied via CSS’s two pseudo-classes, `:invalid` and `:valid`. It applies to `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` elements.
> - Bootstrap scopes the `:invalid` and `:valid` styles to parent `.was-validated` class, usually applied to the `<form>`. Otherwise, any required field without a value shows up as invalid on page load. This way, you may choose when to activate them (typically after form submission is attempted).
> - As a fallback, `.is-invalid` and `.is-valid` classes may be used instead of the pseudo-classes for server side validation. They do not require a .was-validated parent class.

To achieve somewhat of what you're trying to do, taken from the [example here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#custom-styles) you can use custom styles and create tooltips for each input and display a response based on the validation result. You will need to add the `novalidate` property to your `<form>` in order to prevent the default browser validation for this to work.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom01">First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" placeholder="First name" value="Mark" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">
        Looks good!
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom02">Last name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom02" placeholder="Last name" value="Otto" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">
        Looks good!
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustomUsername">Username</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend">@</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustomUsername" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Please choose a username.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom03">City</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom03" placeholder="City" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please provide a valid city.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom04">State</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom04" placeholder="State" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please provide a valid state.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom05">Zip</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom05" placeholder="Zip" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please provide a valid zip.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck" required>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck">
        Agree to terms and conditions
      </label>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        You must agree before submitting.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>

<script>
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
</script>
```

More information on Bootstrap Validation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation